# django.db.utils.OperationalErrror: no such tabel: django_site

Tags: python, django, shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 621, in 
count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 559, in get_count
    return obj.get_aggregation(using, ["__count"])["__count"]
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 544, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site
```

I am trying
Site.objects.count()
and getting this  OperationalError : no such table: django_site

HERE IS MY Site CLASS IN django.contrib.sites models.py file

```
 class Site(models.Model):
      domain = models.CharField(
      _("domain name"),
       max_length=100,
      validators=[_simple_domain_name_validator],
      unique=True,
)
name = models.CharField(_("display name"), max_length=50)

objects = SiteManager()

class Meta:
    db_table = "django_site"
    verbose_name = _("site")
    verbose_name_plural = _("sites")
    ordering = ["domain"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.domain

def natural_key(self):
    return (self.domain,)
```

Check if there is any error and please help and explain clearly as i am beginner.

Comment: did you define a model Site and migrate to the database?

Comment: did you make migrations?

Comment: This is my settings

Comment: yes i did makemigrations

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'organizer',
    'blog',
    'contact'
    
]

Comment: i have shared my code of Site class . See if there is any error

Comment: Remove the db_table parameter from meta. Delete your db.sqlite3 and you migrations. Make migrations again and migrate

Comment: which migrations i should delete becuase i have also created seprate migrations files for model classes

Comment: are you saying to remove db_table = "django_site"

Comment: I mean, if you are not in production, and you don't have anything important in the db, delete all migrations and the db, and yes, that line.

Comment: okay i will do it

Comment: of course create another file named db.sqlite3 in the same location as it was

Comment: i did but after running the command python manage.py migrate now transaction management  error coming

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: Django 4.1.7    ..............